# which Android version should I develop for May 2016

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am new to the android development, I was wondering which Android version should I develop for? Some people told me to go with Kitkat 4.4.4, but some told me to go for 6.0 marshallmellow even though it only has little market share. I am also looking to purchase an android phone for development purpose, hopefully won't break my bank, any suggestions, galaxy??

Comment: For November 2016 it seems that minSdkVersion is ok with 16 (4.1).

Answer (score 0):

**HTC** or **Moto G 3rd Generation** are best for testing purpose because i am also using these.
and apart from this you can build application for **marshmallow** but set min android version to **15**.

enjoy your code time.

Comment: I have HTC inspire 4g and huawei u8665, but they both android 2.3 ish. I just tried updating huawei u8665 to kitkat and failed, and it was an awful time consuming task. And I seem to have broken the firmware of huawei somehow. Do you know of a simpler way to  update the android os on these phones?

Answer (score 0):

As an Android development, I agree with you to buy a new device. It should support Android6.0 better, then you can use it much longer. Below is our company's used version:

    `compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 11
    targetSdkVersion = 19`

The target sdk version is 19 (Kitkat 4.4.4), while compile is 23, by this then you can use more google's sdk support, such as v7 and v4. 
Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The most Stable Version of Android which is enough in your case is 5.1 (API 21) and you can set the minSdkVersion as 11 like you are doing in your current company.

Regarding the Device I recommand you first to Test your app on Debug Mode with a Virtual Emulator, try Genymotion, you will like it, quite fast and Responsive and free for your your personal usage, Then Regarding the device, you can use any device that can support your Targer SDK (19), In case your company gives you a project with Target SDK (23), you can just upgrade the OS Version on your Android Device. 
Good luck